# Discord.py SQL перестала работать комманда leaderboard

Tags: python, mysql, sql, discord.py

Раньше я тестил комманду Leaderboard все работало,теперь он просто не дает ошибок но у всех баланс 0,
еще у меня проблема с тем что у меня при инвайте на другой сервер,происходит ошибка в on_ready() был бы рад если б мне помогли бы и с этим)

```
@client.event
    async def on_ready():
      cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT CHECK (cash >= 0),
        rep INT,
        lvl INT,
        server_id INT,
        upgrade BIGINT
      )""")
        for guild in client.guilds:
          for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(F"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
              cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1 ,{guild.id}, 10)")
              connection.commit()
            else:
              pass
      connection.commit()
      print('Бот присоеденился')
    
    
    @client.command()
    async def leaderboard(ctx):
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'топ 10 сервера')
      counter = 0
      for row in cursor.execute("SELECT name, cash From users WHERE server_id = {} ORDER BY cash DESC LIMIT 10".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        counter += 1
        embed.add_field(name = F'# {counter} | {row[0]} ',value = F'Баланс: {row[1]}',inline = False)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Какая ошибка именно возникает?

Comment: Ошибок 0,но леадерборд не работает должны образом даже если у человека больше денег,то он  будет показыватся как 0 монет